# troubles creating a new object of existing model through association object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to create a new object via an association as so:

```
def create
  @enhancement = current_user.enhancements.create enhancement_params

  if @enhancement.save!
    redirect_to enhancements_path, notice: "Mission Control has receieved your request"
  else
    redirect_to enhancements_path, notice: "Danger! Mission Control could not receive your request!"
  end
end
```

and the **error** I get is:

```
wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)
```

I've also tried

```
@enhancement = current_user.enhancements.new enhancement_params
```

and then for your possible reference, here are the strong parameters I'm passing in

```
def enhancement_params
  params.require(:enhancement).permit(:name, :description, :user_id, :status)
end
```

Association-wise, the model enhancements belongs_to the user model, and the user model has_many enhancements.

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong and a sneaking suspicion I'm missing something super simple, but I've wasted enough time on this. Any ideas what's going on? Is there any other information I can give you?

**Updated -**

I'm just doing

```
 def create
    @enhancement = Enhancement.create enhancement_params
    if @enhancement.save
      redirect_to enhancements_path, notice: "Mission Control has receieved your request"
    else
      redirect_to enhancements_path, notice: "Danger! Mission Control could not receive your request!"
    end
  end
```

here's the **error**:
    wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)

> Started POST "/enhancements" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-03-20 16:29:38
>   -0500 Processing by EnhancementsController#create as HTML   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓",
>   "authenticity_token"=>"pKfKnNGB4CWNSBOOKAe/l6Em+MSV5l+tLS0kDRTCQEc=",
>   "enhancement"=>{"name"=>"Wow what enhancemnt ", "description"=>"such
>   enhamcnet \r\n\r\nvery wow"}, "commit"=>"Save Enhancement"} Completed
>   500 Internal Server Error in 3ms
>
> ArgumentError - wrong number of arguments (1 for 0):
>   activerecord-deprecated_finders (1.0.3)
>   lib/active_record/deprecated_finders/base.rb:28:in `call'
>
>   activerecord (4.0.2) lib/active_record/scoping/named.rb:163:in`block
>   (2 levels) in scope'   activerecord (4.0.2)
>   lib/active_record/relation.rb:270:in `scoping'   activerecord (4.0.2)
>   lib/active_record/scoping/named.rb:163:in`block in scope'
>   activerecord (4.0.2) lib/active_record/persistence.rb:36:in `create'
>
>   app/controllers/enhancements_controller.rb:12:in`create'   actionpack
>   (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in
>   `send_action'   actionpack (4.0.2)
>   lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:189:in`process_action'   actionpack
>   (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in
>   `process_action'   actionpack (4.0.2)
>   lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in`block in process_action'
>   activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:403:in
>   `_run__3594477325221698156__process_action__callbacks'   activesupport
>   (4.0.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in`run_callbacks'
>   actionpack (4.0.2) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in
>   `process_action'   actionpack (4.0.2)
>   lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in`process_action'
>   actionpack (4.0.2)
>   lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:31:in `block in
>   process_action'   activesupport (4.0.2)
>   lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in`block in instrument'
>   activesupport (4.0.2)
>   lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
>
>   activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in`
>   instrument'   actionpack (4.0.2)
>   lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action' 
>   actionpack (4.0.2)
>   lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:245:in`process_action' 
>   activerecord (4.0.2)
>   lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in
>   `process_action'   actionpack (4.0.2)
>   lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:136:in`process'   actionpack (4.0.2)
>   lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:44:in `process'   actionpack
>   (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:195:in`dispatch'   actionpack
>   (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in
>   `dispatch'   actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:231:in`
>   block in action'   actionpack (4.0.2)
>   lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:80:in `dispatch'   actionpack
>   (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:48:in`call'
>   actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:71:in `block
>   in call'   actionpack (4.0.2)
>   lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in`call'   actionpack
>   (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:680:in `call'
>
>   warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in`block in call'   warden
>   (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'   rack (1.5.2)
>   lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in`call'   rack (1.5.2)
>   lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:35:in `call'   rack (1.5.2)
>   lib/rack/head.rb:11:in`call'   actionpack (4.0.2)
>   lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
>
>   actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:241:in`
>   call'   rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
>   rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in`call'
>   actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:486:in
>   `call'   activerecord (4.0.2) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in`
>   call'   activerecord (4.0.2)
>   lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:626:in
>   `call'   activerecord (4.0.2) lib/active_record/migration.rb:369:in`
>   call'   actionpack (4.0.2)
>   lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
>
>   activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:373:in`
>   _run__4163598129264950275__call__callbacks'   activesupport (4.0.2)
>   lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'   actionpack
>   (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in`call'
>   actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:64:in
>   `call'   actionpack (4.0.2)
>   lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:76:in`call'
>   better_errors (1.1.0) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:84:in
>   `protected_app_call'   better_errors (1.1.0)
>   lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:79:in`better_errors_call'
>   better_errors (1.1.0) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:56:in `call'
>
>   actionpack (4.0.2)
>   lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in`call'
>   actionpack (4.0.2)
>   lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
>
>   railties (4.0.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in`call_app'   railties
>   (4.0.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'   activesupport
>   (4.0.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in`block in tagged'
>   activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:25:in
>   `tagged'   activesupport (4.0.2)
>   lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in`tagged'   railties (4.0.2)
>   lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'   actionpack (4.0.2)
>   lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in`call'   rack
>   (1.5.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'   rack (1.5.2)
>   lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in`call'   activesupport (4.0.2)
>   lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:83:in `call'   rack
>   (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in`call'   actionpack (4.0.2)
>   lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'   rack (1.5.2)
>   lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in`call'   railties (4.0.2)
>   lib/rails/engine.rb:511:in `call'   railties (4.0.2)
>   lib/rails/application.rb:97:in`call'   rack (1.5.2)
>   lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'   rack (1.5.2)
>   lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in`call'   rack (1.5.2)
>   lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
>
>   /Users/chris/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in`
>   service'
>   /Users/chris/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in
>   `run'
>
>   /Users/chris/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in`
>   block in start_thread' `

Comment: Not sure if it's because you've been editing a lot to find the solution but: `create` (which looks like the right call) will create and save a new object if validations pass. Then `save!` will save it or raise an exception if validations fail. You probably want to call `build` and then `@enhancement.save` to check if it saved okay. Might be worth sorting that out first.

Comment: Can you share the error stacktrace. Where exactly are you getting the error?

Comment: Updated w/ more info!

Comment: hey, sorry to revoke it, but it wasn't devise. Updated the main post with more info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with:

```
def create
  @enhancement = current_user.enhancements.build enhancement_params

  if @enhancement.save # without bang method, it throws an exception
    redirect_to enhancements_path, notice: "Mission Control has receieved your request"
  else
    redirect_to enhancements_path, notice: "Danger! Mission Control could not receive your request!"
  end
end
```

I can't imagine which method throws the error in that action, so you should check if any `before_filter` (or `before_action` in `Rails 4`) is causing the error.

Comment: You were right. I realized I wasn't configuring the permitted parameters via devise!

Comment: aha. wasn't a before_action, but there was a similar thing in there I didn't know was there that was causing it. Thanks!